# Can a single pipe be used for 2 way communication between parent and a child?

Tags: c, unix, linux-kernel, operating-system, pipe

Suppose I use `pipefdn[2]` and `pipe()` on it , can bidirectional communication be implemented using a single pipe or do you need 2 pipes ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296007/bidirectional-message-passing-between-2-processes-within-an-os

Comment: @sawdust that question you mentioned doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer..

Comment: It has a good answer, which now has an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Though this operation results as success in some cases, but it is not a recommended way , especially in the production code. As pipe() by default dont provide any sync mechanism and moreover the read() can go for an infinite hang, if no data or read() is called before write() from other process.

Recommended way is to always use 2 pipe. pipe1[2], pipe2[2] for two way communication.

For more info please refer the following video description.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Q9CPWuRC6o&list=PLfqABt5AS4FkW5mOn2Tn9ZZLLDwA3kZUY&index=11

Answer (score 0):

No sorry. Linux pipe() is unidirectional. See [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe), and also [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) & [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html). Consider also `AF_UNIX` sockets, see [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch adding in entirely distinct methods like sockets really crosses the line from editing someone else's answer to writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong: But I think you can. The problem is that you probably don't want to do that. First, of all create a simple program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int pd[2];
int num = 2;
int main(){
    pid_t t = fork();
    /* create a child process */
    if(t<0){
        printf("error in fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* create a pipe */
    if(pipe(pd)==-1){
        printf("error in pipe");
        exit(3);
    }
    else if(t==0){
        //close(pd[1]);  // child close writing end
        int r = read(pd[0], &num, sizeof(num));
        if(r<0){
           printf("error while reading");
           exit(2);
        }
        printf("i am the child and i read %d\n",num);
      //  close(pd[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    /* parent process */
    //close(pd[0]);   /* parents closes its reading end
    if(write(pd[1],&num,sizeof(num)<0)){
        printf("error in reading");
        exit(4);
    }
    //close(pd[1]);
    /*parent wait for your child to terminate;*/
    int status;
    wait(&status);
    printf("my child ended with status: %d\n",status);
    return 0;
}
```

Try to play with `close()`. Skip it by putting it in a comment or include it. You will find out that in order this program to run the only really needed system-call close is the one before the child reads. I found here in stack overflow an answer saying that " Because the write-end is open the system waits because a potential write could occur .. " . **Personally, I tried to run it without it and I discovered that it would not terminate.** The other close(), although are a good practice , don't influence the execution. ( I am not sure why that happens maybe someone more experienced can help us).
Now let's examine what you asked:
I can see some problems here:
If two processes write in the same channel you may have race conditions:
They write to the same file descriptor at the same time:

- What if one process reads its own writings instead of those of the process
  it tries to communicate with? How you will know, where in the file you should read?
- What if the one process, writes "above" the writings of the other?

Answer (score -2):

Yes it can, I've done that before. I had a parent and child send each other different messages using the same 2 pipes and receive them correctly. Just make sure you're always reading from the first file descriptor and writing to the second.

Comment: You mean using one pipe ? And 2 file descriptors ?